# Is there a type-safe way to express that a function returns an object of type T when passed a T, but an object of type Partial<T> when passed that?

Tags: typescript

I'm writing functions to sanitize input passed to my CRUD operations; e.g. I don't want it to be possible for the operation to create or update a user to set an internal flag that indicates an unrestricted administrator.

To do this I just use lodash's `_.pick` to project only the known properties out of the input:

```
interface IUser {
    username: string;
    password: password;
}

interface IUserInternal {
    superuser: boolean;
}

function cleanUser(user: IUser): IUser {
    return _.pick(user, 'username', 'password');
}

function createUser(user: IUser) {
    db.create(cleanUser(user));
}

function updateUser(id: string, user: Partial<IUser>) {
    const old = db.get(id);
    db.update(id, {...old, ...cleanUser(user)});
}
```

I can't rely on typechecking here since this is at a service boundary, and I'd like to stick to something quick and dirty for now before adding full blown validation.

The problem above is in the last bit: I can't call `cleanUser()` on a `Partial<IUser>` obviously. I also can't have `cleanUser()` take and return a `Partial<IUser>`, because then I'm losing the type checker making sure I picked all the properties. The implementation itself will work, because pick will just skip properties that aren't found in the source object.

I tried making the signature `cleanUser<T extends Partial<IUser>>(user: T): T` to express I'm returning the same thing being passed in, but just told me the return value isn't assignable to `T`. I tried adding an overload signature `cleanUser<Partial<IUser>>(user: Partial<IUser>)`, but then TS would pick that up even when passing in a regular User.

Is there a clean way to express this, or do I just go "I know what I'm doing" and suppress the type error?

Comment: _I tried adding an overload signature cleanUser<Partial<IUser>>(user: Partial<IUser>), but then TS would pick that up even when passing in a regular User._ You were thinking right, but the order of your overloads is important. TypeScript will match the first signature it finds suitable. In other words, your overload with a full `IUser` should come first, and only then the one with `<Partial<IUser>>`.

Comment: @KarolMajewski Interesting! This leads to the interesting situation where I have to add the overload for `IUser`, then the overload for `Partial<IUser>`, then the implementation signature that's the same as the first overload to get the typechecking in the function body, but it gets the job done.

Comment: I'm surprised TSLint isn't complaining about a redundant function signature here.

Comment: It's not really redundant — it tells _something_ to the compiler. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) for this:

```
function cleanUser(user: IUser): IUser;
function cleanUser(user: Partial<IUser>): Partial<IUser>;
function cleanUser(user): any {
  return _.pick(user, 'username', 'password');
}
```