# Why is this function overload valid as a method signature, but reports an error for a toplevel function?

Tags: typescript

Why does the same set of overload signatures for the same function work fine when the function is a class method, but not when it's defined as a plain function at module toplevel?

```
interface Foo {
    bar: number;
    baz: string;
    bat: boolean;
}

function cleanFoo({bar, baz, bat}: Foo): Foo {
    return {bar, baz, bat}
}

function cleanFooPartial({bar, baz, bat}: Partial<Foo>): Partial<Foo> {
    return {bar, baz, bat}
}

class FooCleaner {
    cleanFooOverload(foo: Foo): Foo;
    cleanFooOverload(foo: Partial<Foo>): Partial<Foo>;
    cleanFooOverload({bar, baz, bat}: Foo): Foo {
        return {bar, baz, bat}
    }
}

function cleanFooOverload(foo: Foo): Foo;
function cleanFooOverload(foo: Partial<Foo>): Partial<Foo>;
function cleanFooOverload({bar, baz, bat} : Foo): Foo {
    return {bar, baz, bat}
}
```

`cleanFoo` is the primary version; `cleanFooPartial` is to show that the same implementation matches the overload that takes and returns a `Partial<Foo>`; `FooCleaner.cleanFooOverload` works fine.

Why does the toplevel definition report this error?

> Overload signature is not compatible with function implementation.

Comment: I can tell you why it happens but I am not sure if it's  a big or not. If you disable `strictFunctionTypes` the error goes away. Class methods are not impacted by `strictFunctionTypes` this is why one raises an error and the other does not (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52667959/what-is-the-purpose-of-bivariancehack-in-typescript-types/52668133#52668133)

Comment: The implementation signature should accept `Partial<Foo>` and not require `Foo`.  The class method doesn't error because it accepts bivariant parameters even with [`--strictFunctionTypes`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#strict-function-types) enabled, but bivariant parameters aren't type safe.

Comment: @jcalz I don't quite want to do that; if I add a new property to `Foo`, I *want* the implementation to report an error until I include it there. Making the function `Partial<Foo> => Partial<Foo>` loses that check.

Comment: How to do this in a type safe way would I suppose be the actual question here. Except I already asked that question yesterday and got the bivariant overload as an answer on it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54634788/is-there-a-type-safe-way-to-express-that-a-function-returns-an-object-of-type-t

Comment: So.. maybe make the implementation signature accept a `Partial<Foo>` but return a `{ [K in keyof Foo]: Foo[K] | undefined }` (which is *like* `Partial<Foo>` except it explicitly claims to return an object with all the keys even if their values might be `undefined`).